# Handling Redirect 302 in Java

Tags: java, http, redirect

I have been tryig to handle a redirect(302) in java code... And the code I have uses
`org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient` which doesn't declare `setRedirectStrategy()`, so I have to write my own redirect implementation :

```
private void loadHttp302Request(HttpMethod method, HttpClient client,
            int status, String urlString) throws HttpException, IOException {
        if (status!=302)
            return;
        String[] url = urlString.split("/");
        logger.debug("Method -> loadHttp302Request -> Location : " + method.getResponseHeader("Location")
                .getValue());

        logger.debug("Method -> loadHttp302Request -> Cookies : " + method.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
                .getValue());

        logger.debug("Method -> loadHttp302Request -> Referrer : " + url[0]+"//"+url[2]);

        HttpMethod theMethod = new GetMethod(urlString+method.getResponseHeader("Location")
                .getValue());
        theMethod.setRequestHeader("Cookie", method.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
                .getValue());
        theMethod.setRequestHeader("Referrer",url[0]+"//"+url[2]);
        int _status = client.executeMethod(theMethod);
        logger.debug("Method -> loadHttp302Request -> Status : " + _status);
        method = theMethod;
    }
```

Once this is executed, the status code equals 200, so it seems like everything worked, but the response body and responsestream are both null. I've been able to sniff the TCP Stream with wireshark and as far as Wireshark is concerned, I receive back the whole response body from my redirect code... So I am not sure what I am doing wrong or what to look for next... Ideally It would be nice if I could use `setRedirectStrategy()`, but because it is a Client's code :p I am stuck using the `org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient`...

I have debugged down the `executeMethod()` and found that when reading the response from the input stream, it seems to receive nothing, even though wireshark most certainly shows that I received the full response body.

Any ideas would be appreciated :)

Comment: In `getMethod` `urlString` should be replaced by `url[0]+"//"+url[2]` isn't it?

Comment: Nope... Then you will have a path = http://www.abc.com/www.abc.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`method = theMethod;` at the end of `loadHttp302Request` isn't going to do anything useful. When `loadHttp302Request` returns, the `method` object pointer in your calling (java) method is still going to be pointing to the original HttpMethod object.

Return `theMethod`from `loadHttp302Request` and get the response contents from that instead.

Comment: Thank's for the answer. I returned `theMethod` from `loadHttp302Request` method and instead of copying the content of `theMethod` I did the following :
`int status = httpClient.executeMethod(theMethod);
        HttpMethod requestMethod = loadHttp302Request(theMethod, httpClient, status, urlStr);
        if (requestMethod != null) {
         theMethod = requestMethod;
        }`
Now, It's opening the webpage, but when I click on any link with in the webpage it takes me back to my login page. Any idea's?

Comment: Possibly you're not retaining and resending the session cookie correctly. I'd check that first.

Comment: How will I be able to retain and resend the session cookies?

Comment: HttpClient should provide a facility for doing that. Check the docs or open a new SO question.

Comment: Please follow up on the next question, if you can me help me out with this thing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661984/how-to-re-send-or-retain-a-session-cookie